# Hibernate addScalar to Hibernate.FLOAT round off

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, floating-point

```
Query qry = session.createSQLQuery(qrystr)
.addScalar("id", Hibernate.INTEGER)
.addScalar("balance",Hibernate.FLOAT);

    Object[] headerDetails=(Object[])qry.uniqueResult();
    session.close();
    System.out.println("balance"+headerDetails[1]);
```

for the above code when the query is excuted the value 66996956 from the database returns as 6.6996956E7.

Even for DOUBLE the output is 6.6996956E7. But when math.BIG_DECIMAL is provided the value is correct. Why there is a problem in double and float. And in the code i can introduce bigdecimal as rest of data is in float.

Answer (score 0):

66996956 and 6.6996956E7 are the same value, displayed differently. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString%28float%29) to understand why it's displayed this way:

> If m is less than 10^-3 or greater than or equal to 10^7, then it is
>   represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation."

If you don't mind about the loss of precision that floats and doubles necessarily have (and even more for large values), then use them. If you want an absolutely precise value, then use BigDecimal.

Comment: can understand both are same value, Need to know how to display in normal format at UI